# PHP file_get contents blocked by the webserver

Tags: php, web-crawler, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get contents from another webpage but the remote server keeps blocking me If I use curl or send a 403 forbidden if I use file_get_contents

```
ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('log_errors', 'Off');

function returnRandomUserAgent() {

  $aBrowser = array('Firefox', 'Safari', 'Opera', 'Flock', 'Internet Explorer', 'Seamonkey', 'Tor Browser', 'GNU IceCat', 'CriOS', 'TenFourFox',
    'SeaMonkey', 'B-l-i-t-z-B-O-T', 'Konqueror', 'Mobile', 'Konqueror', 'Netscape', 'Chrome', 'Dragon', 'SeaMonkey', 'Maxthon', 'IBrowse'
  );

  $aSystem = array('Windows 3.1', 'Windows 95', 'Windows 98', 'Windows 2000', 'Windows NT', 'Linux 2.4.22-10mdk', 'FreeBSD',
    'Windows XP', 'Windows Vista', 'Redhat Linux', 'Ubuntu', 'Fedora', 'AmigaOS', 'BackTrack Linux', 'iPad', 'BlackBerry', 'Unix',
    'CentOS Linux', 'Debian Linux', 'Macintosh', 'Android', 'iPhone', 'Windows NT 6.1', 'BeOS', 'OS 10.5', 'Nokia', 'Arch Linux',
    'Ark Linux', 'BitLinux', 'Conectiva (Mandriva)', 'CRUX Linux', 'Damn Small Linux', 'DeLi Linux', 'Ubuntu', 'BigLinux', 'Edubuntu'
  );

  $locals = array('cs-CZ', 'en-US', 'sk-SK', 'pt-BR', 'sq_AL', 'sq', 'ar_DZ', 'ar_BH', 'ar_EG', 'ar_IQ', 'ar_JO',
    'ar_KW', 'ar_LB', 'ar_LY', 'ar_MA', 'ar_OM', 'ar_QA', 'ar_SA', 'ar_SD', 'ar_SY', 'ar_TN', 'ar_AE', 'ar_YE', 'ar',
    'be_BY', 'be', 'bg_BG', 'bg', 'ca_ES', 'ca', 'zh_CN', 'zh_HK', 'zh_SG', 'zh_TW', 'zh', 'hr_HR', 'hr', 'cs_CZ', 'cs',
    'da_DK', 'da', 'nl_BE', 'nl_NL', 'nl', 'en_AU', 'en_CA', 'en_IN', 'en_IE', 'en_MT', 'en_NZ', 'en_PH', 'en_SG', 'en_ZA',
    'en_GB', 'en_US', 'en', 'et_EE', 'et', 'fi_FI', 'fi', 'fr_BE', 'fr_CA', 'fr_FR', 'fr_LU', 'fr_CH', 'fr', 'de_AT', 'de_DE'
  );

  return $aBrowser[rand(0, count($aBrowser) - 1)] . '/' . rand(1, 20) . '.' . rand(0, 20) . ' (' . $aSystem[rand(0, count($aSystem) - 1)] . ' ' . rand(1, 7) . '.' . rand(0, 9) . '; ' . $locals[rand(0, count($locals) - 1)] . ';)';
}

$browser = returnRandomUserAgent();

ini_set('user_agent',$browser);

$contents = file_get_contents("https://webpage_url_here");

echo $contents
```

But I get

```
 Warning: file_get_contents("https://webpage_url_here"): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /home/USER/public_html/crawler.php on line 31
```

I tried curl like this

```
function curl($url){

$headers[]  = "User-Agent:".returnRandomUserAgent();
$headers[]  = "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$headers[]  = "Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5";
$headers[]  = "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate";
$headers[]  = "Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$headers[]  = "Keep-Alive:115";
$headers[]  = "Connection:keep-alive";
$headers[]  = "Cache-Control:max-age=0";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $data;
```

}

```
$data = curl('https://webpage_url_here');
```

But I get "You have been blocked"

Is there any work around to be able to get the contents of this page to parse and extract links?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Try using Curl with Proxies, to bypass your blocked/filtered IP by the target webserver.
Checkout https://beamtic.com/using-proxies-with-curl for more info.

Comment: One of the website that offer free IPs and PORTS http://spys.one/en/

Comment: Used different IPs and always blocked "curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'IP:PORT');"

Comment: Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you need to encode the URI with

```
urlencode()
```

before

```
file_get_contents()
```

For reference Click [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)!

Comment: No special characters